# is this the correct way to solve this question?

Tags: probability

when two fair dice are rolled,the odds of throwing a 'double'(two dice with the same number) is 1:5.
if two dice are rolled 400 times ,the best estimate of the number of times you would NOT get a double would be ___?

my work:

400/2=80/2=40
is this the correct answer to the solution and if not ,what is the correct answer to this question?

Comment: Is that the correct way to solve it?  Um, no.

Comment: then whats the correct solution to solve this question?

Comment: It says that the “odds” of getting a double is 1:5. Do you know what that means?

Comment: That was in response to your original post where you asked a question about cards and getting only face cards and then you just mashed a bunch of keys.   Mashing a bunch of keys is not the way to do anything.

Comment: Please use the actual question as the title of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by calculating the probability of getting a double of a particular number (1 for instance).

Each dice has 6 numbers, so the probably of getting 1 on a single dice is $\left(\frac 16\right)$.  The probability of getting 1 on both dice is the product of the probabilities of getting 1 on each individual dice: $$\left(\frac 16\right)\left(\frac 16\right)=\left(\frac{1}{36}\right)$$

Now, multiply that result by 6 to calculate the probability of getting a double of any of the 6 numbers.

$$\left(\frac{1}{36}\right)6=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$

The probability of rolling a double is $\frac 16$.

To calculate the theoretical amount of rolls (out of 400) that will not be doubles, take 1 minus the probability of rolling a double, and then multiple that result by 400.

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)400=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)400=333$$ (I rounded to the nearest whole number)

Comment: so the answer to this question is 333 for sure right?

Comment: @Tanisha Joshi Yes.  Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

So lets try to calculate the number of times we would throw a 'double', given the probability is 1:5 , and n=400.

So if we were to throw the pair of two dice once, there is 1/5 chance that they would be a double. If we were to throw it again, the probability will still stay the same; so no matter how many times you throw the dice, the probability will always be 1/5.

The probability of 1/5 means that if we were to throw our pair of dice 5 times, atleast 1 of those times the dice will be a 'double', because we multiply the number of times we rolled our dice, 5, by the probability. So we end up $5*\frac{1}{5}=1$, the number of times a double occurred if we threw the dice 5 times. To calculate the number of times a 'double' was thrown we use the same logic, we multiply the number of times we threw the dice by the probability: $400*\frac{1}{5}=80$, so out of the 400 dice rolls, only 80, will be double.

To calculate the number of rolls that were not a double, we minus the total number of rolls by the number of rolls where a double occured: $400-80=320$. So out of the 400 dice rolls, 320 of them will not be a double.

Comment: so the number of times you would NOT get a double would be 320?

Comment: so the anwer is 320/

Comment: The probability is not 1:5. The odds are 1:5

Comment: yes,but the answer is 320 of not being a double

Comment: To convert the odds to probability, divide the odds by one plus the odds.

Comment: Most of your sentences in your answer are missing a critical word.  "*Expected*"!  So it should have read for instance "*if we were to throw our pair of dice five times, the* **expected** *number of times we throw a double would be $1$*" (*ignoring the mistake between the probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ versus $\frac{1}{6}$ which should already have been explained*).  Later, "*So out of the 400 dice rolls, the* **expected** *number of times it is not a double would be 320.*"  Do not confuse an expected number to be a guaranteed number.  I can roll six times and not get a $1$ for instance.

Comment: @notMyName that’s incorrect.  The probability of rolling a double is 1/6.  How did you get 1/5?

Comment: @Tanisha Joshi No. It’s 333.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw It says in the problem that it is 1/5

Comment: That’s weird . I didn’t see that until just now.